# How to load jekyll data from sub-folder dynamically using page variable as data file name

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I learned how to load data from `_data/sub-folder` from [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3569) as following:

```
site.data[page.folderName].fooList
```

But could not figure out how to load data from `_data/sub-folder` when using page variable as the data file name. Page front-matter:

```
---
layout: default
title: Foo
folderName: foo
dataFileName: fooList
---
```

I tried:

```
site.data[page.folderName][page.dataFileName]     // did not work
```

How to load data using page variable (`page.dataFileName`) as data file name?

Comment: This is supposed to work. You might have a mismatch with file name, eg: foolist != fooList or something like this.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Thanks! I was messing up with the variable name (camel case)  and filename (`_`)